# Source file is blank and Git doesn't show it ever existed

Tags: xcode, git

I was coding earlier and decided to not commit. When I revisited the project later in the day, I went to Source Code/Discard All Changes. I didn't like the direction I was taking the project, so I figured I would discard changes and then reclone my project into another folder to get back to my original state. I've been working on this project for a few weeks now, and this one particular file has been part of the project since the beginning.

It's showing up in my project tree on the left side of XCode, but it's empty. When I look in the folder, it's straight up missing. No problem, I'll restore from github. This is where the problem is. It doesn't show up in any of my commits. I don't see this file ever existed, but if I look at some of my commits, I see references to the file. Is there any way for me to recover this file, or do I need to start coding on it again? This really sucks... :(

I've done 'git log --full-history -- path/to/file' and it doesn't find anything at all. I do the same for a known good file, and it shows the file. This file isn't in my history at all. I thought that was the whole point of git was to be able to go back in time if something happened?

Comment: When you write "if I look at some of my commits, I see references to the file", where did you see these references? In some commit messages?

Comment: It looked like there were md5 hashes associated with the filename. The filename was InternalWebBrowser.swift, and the only thing I could find were references to the filename but there was no code assocated. I've been unable to recover, so I took a very old file and I'm starting to rebuild